# windows 10 can't boot when I move nvme to usb

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, usb-storage

### problem description

#### 0. before & good

my win10 laptop, win10 on nvme ssd, everything is ok

- grub2 boorloader ok
- win10 bootloader ok
- boot by EFI

  - sec boot is off (in bios)

#### 1. changes & problem

I remove the ssd and put it in a usb hard drive case，
wish to boot from this usb and use the win10 again.

It can't boot into windows system anymore.

- but ubuntu can work this way.
- I remember old days xp/win7 on IDE/SATA disk, also work this way (only need make sure bios has right IDE/AHCI disk mode)
- win10 booting in this page about 30 seconds, almost next page to login, but got reboot directly

[image: booting & fail]

#### 2. check1: boot fix

all bootloader got this same problem.
I also reinstall grub2, win bootmgr ; all the same.

I ask question on MS site, only got 'use install disc to fix boot issue', which i tried many times.

#### 3. check2: back & good

I put the ssd into nvme again, all is well.

I feel that, it's not about  bootload problem, it's about system config

- the driver of boot disk ?
- some MS Piracy Protection Mechanism ? （it's genuine system, lenovo win10 pro

### what I want to know

What is the reason ?
how to overcome it effectively rather than reinstall

---

I'm sure I'm not the only one with this problem,

For example, this guy has the same problem

https://www.mobile01.com/topicdetail.php?f=514&t=6375963

Answer (score 0):

You should have edited registry at

`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\uaspstor with Start = 0`

instead of doing it with commands. This way it stays permanently on and Windows boots up just fine.